# C++ vector: std::out_of_range Error

Tags: c++

I have a structure in which I have a vector

```
vector<int> accept;
```

In my program , when I try to insert a value at a specific index. I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

In each iteration of my loop, I increment the AlphabetCounter and place a value at that specific index like the code given below :

```
AlphabetCounter=AlphabetCounter+1;

NewNextStateDouble.accept.at(AlphabetCounter)=1;
```

AlphabetCounter=-1 before starting the loop.

I don't get it why out of range error is occuring.

Comment: Did you reserve enough space for the vector beforehand? Or you can use `push_back` to insert the elements.

Comment: @AdriC.S. No, I didn't reserve the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only grow a vector by using these two methods below:

---

Using the [`resize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wezs0zy6.aspx) method:

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;
v1.resize( 5 );
```

---

Using the [`push_back()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fthz5xd.aspx) method for dynamically increasing the size of the vector:

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;

for( int i = 0; i != 10; ++i )
{
  my_vector.push_back( i );
}

std::cout << "The vector size is: " << my_vector.size() << std::endl;
```

---

In your situation, you have to know that subscripting does not add elements, as the standard says:

> The subscript operator on vector (and string) fetches an existing
>   element; it does not add an element.

Also some recommendations about subscripting can be seen below.

> ### Subscript Only Elements that are Known to Exist!
>
> It is **crucially important** to understand that we may use the subscript operator
>   (the `[]` operator) to **fetch only elements that actually exist**. ( For example, see the code below )
>
> **It is an error to subscript an element that doesn’t exist**, but it is an error that
>   the compiler is unlikely to detect. Instead, the value we get at run time is
>   undefined. (usually, an `out_of_range` exception)
>
> Attempting to subscript elements that do not exist is, unfortunately, an
>   extremely common and pernicious programming error. So-called buffer
>   overflow errors are the result of subscripting elements that don’t exist. Such
>   bugs are the most common cause of security problems in PC and other
>   applications.

```
vector<int> ivec; // empty vector
cout << ivec[0]; // error: ivec has no elements!
vector<int> ivec2(10); // vector with ten elements
cout << ivec2[10]; // error: ivec2 has elements 0 . . . 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You vector must have at least `AlphabetCounter` + 1 elements when you want to change a value at the position `AlphabetCounter`. You must make sure that is the case before you access the value.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` does not grow to a specific index if the vector does not have enough elements. If you know the size (you need that to insert at a specific index) then you should `resize()` the vector to the appropriate size.

Answer (score 1):

you have created an empty vector....use `accept.push_back(5)` ....

```
    Description of push_back() method
    Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. 
The content of val is copied (or moved) to the new element.

    This effectively increases the container size by one, which causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if- the new vector size 
surpasses the current vector capacity.
```